# Flutter :: qrscan.dart package does not work

Tags: flutter, qr-code

import 'package:qrscan/qrscan.dart' as qrscanner;

RaisedButton(
elevation: 4,
child: Text('Scan QR'),
color: Colors.amberAccent,
shape: StadiumBorder(),
onPressed: () async {
scanResult = await qrscanner.scan();
// scanResult = 'hai';
setState(() {});
}),
[image: I try to use qrscan.dart package (^0.2.22) but while I push my raisedbutton, it just appear flashlight logo.Is there something that i missed? Probably somebody can help me how to make it work. Thx a lot for your help.]

Comment: Is there something that i missed?
Probably somebody can help me how to make it work. Thx a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you check if you have permissions for camera usage? From the package repo, it seems that the permissions are not requested anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar trouble with you today. I'm using realme C2 and I try to give permission to the app manually.
here my step:

open

1. setting.
2. security.
3. permission.
4. switch to app tab.
5. find ur QR app
6. switch camera permission to 'allow'

I hope it can help.

[image: my permission]